# Scalar Property and Navigational Property EDMX

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework

What is Scalar property and Navigational Property in Entity Frame work Model?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Basically a scalar property is mapped to a column (int, string, ...)
A navigation property is mapped to a relation. e.g Order.OrderDetails brings you to all ORderDetails of a specific order.